# Forward Outlook request to SharePoint List

Tags: email, outlook

Looking for a way to forward emails from outlook to a sharepoint list for cataloging: Workflow would be similar to this:

Email received, forward to SharePoint List, List would parse out Time, Sender, Subject, and have a link to the actual email.

Not necessary to use a list, but that was just the first thing that came to mind.

I can send the email to SharePoint no problem, but the rest I am stumped on. Any ideas?

Comment: SharePoint version ?

Comment: it is the one included in our corporate o365 suite.Not sure of the official verison. Can probably find out.

Comment: So you are using SharePoint Online, not an on-prem Server?  If so, you are automatically on the latest version.

Comment: When you say you "can send the email to SharPoint no problem", are you already getting that email into a SharePoint list, and just trying to figure out what to do with it afterwards?

Comment: What I am trying to do is forward certain emails to sharepoint so that I can track them properly. So, I would receive an email, forward to sharepoint (no issue just sending to  a folder) but I am looking to set up something to track them. So I guess the answer is no, I am not sending to a list yet. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: In my ideal situation, I would forward an email and it would make a list item with: Date, Sender, Subject, and link to actual email. Not sure if using a list is the best way to do this it was just the first idea that popped into my head.\